# Get each nth element of iterator range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std

Is there any standard implementation (meaning stdlib or boost) of an iterator that wraps another iterator and gives only each nth element of it?

I first thought this would be possible with a fitting predicate and boost::filter_iterator, but the predicate gets only the value and not the base iterator, so it cannot tell the distance to the start.

**Edit** 
To give some more information:
The iterator should be compatible with functions like `std::transform` or `std::copy`.
So it should be used like stdlib iterators.

Similar questions:
[C++/STL: std::transform with given stride?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476425/c-stl-stdtransform-with-given-stride) 
[Non-unit iterator stride with non-random access iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387569/non-unit-iterator-stride-with-non-random-access-iterators)

Comment: Can't you do e.g. `it += x` yourself? Or use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)?

Comment: No I cannot do this, as this is outside my reach. I want to pass the iterator to a function, that has an interface like `fn(beginIterator, endIterator)`.

Comment: Do a search for e.g. [`c++ iterator adaptor`](https://www.google.se/search?q=c%2B%2B+iterator+adaptor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Well the question was about an existing one, so I could prevent doing it on my own. (I am afraid that there are some corner cases, where the implementation is not that trivial.) I already searched for some but I do not know the keywords to find exact problem I am facing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boost.Range provides [a stride adaptor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html). Using `boost::begin`/`boost::end` would net you the associated iterators.

Comment: I think that is what I am searching for. I can't believe I did not remember `stride` as the word I was looking for.

Comment: I am afraid that this is not of use for me as I do not use Boost ranges.

Comment: @Nobody You may want to amend your question then.

Comment: It seems like one can rip out `strided_iterator`/`make_strided_iterator` from `boost::range_detail` but I assume that there is no guarantee that they will stay if they are in a detail namespace.

Comment: @Nobody: What do you mean when you say that you do not use Boost ranges? "Boost range" is a concept that is modeled by many types, including standard containers (`std::list`, `std::vector`, etc.) and pair of iterators (`std::pair<iterator_type, some_iterator>`). Thereby, I don't really see how you could not be using Boost ranges (if you have two iterators denoting a begin and an end, then you can make a Boost range out of it simply by putting them in a pair).

Comment: And like Luc said, if you want to work with a stride iterator rather than a stride range, you can always use `begin` and `end` to get the underlying iterators.

Comment: Note however that `strided` is a Single Pass Range, meaning that you wouldn't be able to use it with all algorithms.

Comment: @LucTouraille: That two Lucs are a bit confusing :) I did in fact not have a look at Boost.Range up to now. It looked to me like it was a type, that would not be compatible with stdlib iterator functions.

Comment: @Nobody For future reference, the different libraries that make up the Boost collection of libraries are referred to with a dot: Boost.MPL, Boost.Iterators, Boost.Proto, Boost.Range etc. An entity in the `boost` namespace is qualified with help from the scope resolution operator: `boost::pair`, `boost::reference_wrapper` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `boost::filter_iterator` with predicate like:

```
 template< typename T, int N >
 struct EveryNth {
    bool operator()(const T&) { return m_count++ % N == 0; }
    EveryNth() : m_count(0) {}
    private:
      int m_count;
 };
```

Comment: While this will work for straight forward iteration it will fail on more complex access patterns.

Comment: What patterns exactly? The question is about `Get each nth element`.

Comment: You are right in that my question only asks for forward iteration. I thought of patterns like: Go forward and rewind or binary search.

Comment: aha, ok - in that case you are right: it won't work for those scenarios.