# map function in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm not sure if there exists a function in OpenCV (C++) to do this.

I want to call a custom defined function for every pixel of an cv::Mat in OpenCV and the entire result should be stored in a matrix.

Can I do this in a single line of code (something similar to map function in Python)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried this but according to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) there are STL style iterators for accessing the elements of a matrix:

```
// compute sum of positive matrix elements, iterator-based variant
double sum=0;
MatConstIterator_<double> it = M.begin<double>(), it_end = M.end<double>();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
    sum += std::max(*it, 0.);
```

If they are implemented correctly you should be able to use them with std::for_each approximately like this

```
std::for_each(M.begin<double>(), M.end<double>(), [](double& e) { /* do something with e */ });
```

Comment: Your lambda should have `double& e` as a parameter. Using `double` will make a copy and not assign to the image data.

Comment: This looks like a good idea. I wonder if we could do it for an entire row instead of a pixel;

Comment: You could increase the stepsize to the row length using an adaptor as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726466/get-each-nth-element-of-iterator-range